# Конвертировать Hex в UTF-8

Tags: python-3.x

Есть строка:
'0x0F 0x00 0x39 0x32 0x2E 0x30 0x2E 0x34 0x35 0x31 0x35 0x00'
Хочу конвертировать её в читаемый формат.
Пытаюсь сделать таким вот образом:

```
fff = '0x0F 0x00 0x39 0x32 0x2E 0x30 0x2E 0x34 0x35 0x31 0x35 0x00'
bytes_object = bytes.fromhex(fff)
print(bytes_object.decode("UTF-8"))
```

Получаю трейсбек:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../check.py", line 14, in <module>
    bytes_object = bytes.fromhex(fff)
ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1
```

Есть у кого идеи, что именно я делаю не так и как правильно вытащить из этого хекса необходимые данные?
Онлайн конвертер говорит, что должно быть вот такое вот значение там: **92.0.4515**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52777268/how-do-i-convert-hex-to-utf-8
Там тот же вопрос, хороший ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите пробелы и `0x` из строки сначала:

```
fff = '0x0F 0x00 0x39 0x32 0x2E 0x30 0x2E 0x34 0x35 0x31 0x35 0x00'
bytes_object = bytes.fromhex(fff.replace(' ', '').replace('0x', ''))
print(bytes_object.decode("UTF-8"))
```

Но всё-равно там в начале ещё `0F` и `00` останутся и в конце `00`, они не преобразуются в печатные символы:

```
�92.0.4515�
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fff = '0x0F 0x00 0x39 0x32 0x2E 0x30 0x2E 0x34 0x35 0x31 0x35 0x00'.split()
print(fff)
bytes_object = [bytes.fromhex(x[2::]) for x in fff]
print(bytes_object)
res = [x.decode("UTF-8") for x in bytes_object]
print(res)
print(''.join(res))
#print(bytes_object.decode("UTF-8"))
```